# Strange inline height being added by browsers

Tags: php, css, browser, inline

this is my first post here (though I visit regularly).

FF, Chrome and Safari are all adding their own css to a div.

This is how the div looks in the actual php file and also if you view the page source.

```
<div class="layout content clearfix">
```

However on FF, Chrome and Safari (though not IE9) height is being added and when I use "inspect elements" I see this

```
<div class="layout content clearfix" style="height: 2700px;">
```

Can anyone tell me why or how to remove it?

Comment: Given that it's an inline style, Do you have an jquery plugins, javascript code, browser extensions, etc. with the same class names as either layout, content, or clearfix? Try removing classes 1 by 1 to narrow it down.

Comment: I am too new here just to comment, but I +1 for what Tim said, it does look like Javascript behaviour. Also I will take a punt and say that if it doesn't happen in IE, are there any JS errors in IE, also does the problem start happening in IE when you have the F12 developer tools open, as a rogue console.log might be preventing the code that is causing the issue form running If you want better help, you will need to post more code :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a single browser add inline CSS to any elements. Though you can add Reset CSS for all browser which you can get it from  [here](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

Considering your problem, you can search for any JavaScript in your code which are altering the behavior of the div. if yes you have option to remove JS or class which is not required.

Comment: That's a great help actually.  I am working on a site for a client (a non-disclosure agreement means a cant share the code) that contains a custom plugin that I'm pretty sure is trying to drive me slowly insane!  I dont have access to all of the files so its hard to find the problem but you have given me a great starting place, tyvm